# Portable Class Library and Expression Blend

Tags: c#, silverlight, expression-blend

Which version of expression blend supports portable class library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the What's new in [Expression Blend Service Pack 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134806%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

> Portable assemblies support
>
> **Expression Blend 4 SP2 supports the installation of portable class
>   library projects.** In Visual Studio, portable library tools provide the
>   ability to create new class libraries targeting various .NET platforms
>   without the need to recompile your project. Portable class libraries
>   makes it possible to store most of the application logic in portable
>   assemblies, and then implements the logic in applications that have
>   form-factor specific user interfaces.